# how to export json file in grails?

Tags: json, grails, export, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am using export plugin

```
compile ":export:1.5"
```

controller code:

```
def exportJson(){
    if(!params.max) params.max = 10

    if(params.formattext){
        response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.formattext]
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=BookList.${params.formattext}")


        exportService.export(params.formattext, response.outputStream,Book.list(),[:], [:])
    }
    response action:'index'
}
```

Gsp Code :-

```
<g:link action="exportJson" params="[formattext:'json']" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="margin-right: 30px; float: right; margin-top: 10px;" >Export Rules</g:link></div>
```

while i am trying to export book list in json file its giving me error

```
No bean named 'jsonExporter' is defined. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No bean named 'jsonExporter' is defined
```

Comment: You have : params="[formattext:'json']"   ...  According to http://grails.org/plugin/export  formats (Formats which should be displayed, List of Strings, e.g. ['csv', 'excel', 'ods', 'pdf', 'rtf', 'xml']). I think if I understand correctly you are trying to export out to JSON ? or maybe you are confusing yourself and you mean to export JSON to CSV or pdf or something and formattext should be one of those instead

Comment: i want export in json format..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [export plugi](http://grails.org/plugin/export)n for Grails, you will need to implement your own JSON exporter. It's not included by default, but if you implement the [Exporter](https://github.com/gpc/grails-export/blob/master/src/groovy/de/andreasschmitt/export/exporter/Exporter.groovy) interface and register it as a prototype bean in your `Resources.groovy` then you should be able to use your own JSON exporter.